# Google drive hacked

Tags: google-drive, hacked

Someone hacked my google drive and restricted me from viewing my own files. I have their user name, LaLa LaLa. How do I find out who that person is? No Email address beside it like usual.

Comment: change your password

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "restricted me from viewing my own files" but in any case the first that you should do is to follow the instructions on [Make your account more secure](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/46526?hl=en).

Then

1. Disable the file synchronization with your devices.
2. Check your devices for malware
3. Try to recover accesible versions of your files. For details checkout [View activity & file versions](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)